# Apple push notification not working

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

```
 NSLog(@"push notification in process");
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Entering above code in `appdelegate.m` file in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method

I am getting error message as follows: 

Error :

```
Failed to get token, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x20021380 
{
NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application
}
```

Comment: I want to implement push notification to my app can you help me?

Comment: @vivek There lot of help available on stackoverflow and google

Comment: I searched on net about this but I didnt get how to use backend for this

Comment: what things require from backend? means how to setup backend for that

Comment: @vivek - I dont know about how it works on backend - I assume it will be PHP web backend and there will be an UI through which admin can send Push Notification to iphone - and i have implemented code on iphone side only

Comment: ok so we just have to enable notification from apple to our provising profile and then anything else needed at the time of publishing app?

Comment: keep in mind there are settings in your provisioning profile to enable APNS  - These details are generally needs to be provided when you are making provisioning profile

Comment: and  How to send notification to APNS from server...do you have any idea? As I have read on net it require .pem file .what is that do you know that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be due to a number of issues.  See if any of the following fix it:

- check your AppID has been enabled for push notifications in the provisioning portal
- check your profile for the string: aps-environment
- check that you are using a named profile (not a wildcard)
- check that the capitalisation on your certificate matches your product name (they are case sensitive)

If these fail then the issue could be due to the provisioning profile in Xcode.  If you created your provisioning profile before configuring the AppID for push, try regenerating and installing a new profile.

Comment: I have --> configured App Id --> enabled Push Notification --> Generated CSR downloaded --> APNS SSL certificate

Comment: Added some additional things to check

Comment: Now my device is coming up with blank screen. I think so it got hanged   i am not able to switch it off...